# Clustering: Finding a Average Reading

Tags: java, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I am looking into finding algorithm within the area of clustering or machine learning which will facilitate or creating a typical data reading for a group of readings. The issue is that it must facilitate time series data; thus some traditional (k-means) techniques are not as useful.

Can anyone recommend places to look or particular algorithms that would provide a typical reading and relatively simple to implement (in Java), manipulate and understand?

Comment: Have you considered e.g. k-medoids, where each cluster is represented by a **member**, i.e. in your case a **representative time series**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an idea. Try to convert all data types into time, then you will have vectors of the same type (time), then any clustering strategy will work fine.

By converting to time I actually mean that any measurement or data type we know about has a time in its nature. Time is not a 4-th dimension, as many think! Time is actually 0-dimension. Even a point of no physical dimensions which may not exist in space, exists in time.

Distance, weight, temperature, pressure, directions, speed... all measures we do can be converted into certain functions of time.

I have tried this approach on several projects and it payed back with really nice solutions.

Hope, this might help you here as well.

Answer (score 0):

For most machine learning problems in Java, [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) usually works pretty well.
See, for example: http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/mobasher/classes/ect584/weka/k-means.html